Update Pandas DataFrame slice row-wise using dictionary
Question
I am updating the values in a slice of a pandas.DataFrame by row such that each row of the slice has unique value. I am using pandas version 2.2.3.
I have found an approach that seems to work by using a dictionary of the form {row_index: row_value} (see Minimal working example 1).
I would like to understand:

if / why / how the approach in MWE 1 works and if it is a reasonable way of solving the problem.
if there could be any unexpected behaviour by using this approach
why the approach in MWE 2 does not work / raises error
if there are any other more appropriate methods to achieve this.

I can't find any relevant information about this approach on SO or elsewhere.
My exact use case is slightly different to MWE 1, details of the differences are listed at the bottom, in case they are relevant.

Minimal working example 1 (works)
Here it seems that dictionary values are indeed mapped to the row corresponding to each dictionary key
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [None, None], 'b': [None, None], 'c': [None, None]})
>>> df.loc[df.index, df.columns] = {0: 1, 1: 2}
>>> df
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2

Minimal working example 2 (raises error)
Here, just by selecting the entire dataframe in a different way, an error is raised.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [None, None], 'b': [None, None], 'c': [None, None]})
>>> df2.loc[:, :] = {0: 1, 1: 2}
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.


Similar question on SO
This answer to a similar question explains why a dictionary's keys appear in a row when doing df.iloc[0] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} which is more confusing yet.

Details of what I'm doing
My exact use case differs slightly to MWE 1 in that I have a larger dataframe with some contiguous NaN values, so I am updating that slice/subset of the dataframe with df.loc[df_index_subset, df_columns_subset] instead of  selecting the entire dataframe with df.loc[df.index, df.columns].
However, the behaviour is the same as in Minimal working example 1, it fills the slice of the dataframe by row according to the dictionary's key-value pairs.

I reworded the question to clarify I am looking for an explanation rather than an alternative code snippet.

Pandas requires index alignment. You should either provide an array/list of the exact size of the slice, or a DataFrame/Series.
In your case you could use:
df2.loc[:, :] = pd.DataFrame({0: 1, 1: 2}, index=df2.columns).T

Output:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2


Thank you for your answer. While helpful, I'm not sure it fully explains why MWE 1 does work (and how this differs from MWE 2) which is the key issue.

From your description in "Details of what I'm doing", I guess you're looking to map index with a dict.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cols = list('abcde')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, len(cols))), columns=cols)

map_dict = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3}
df.loc[:,'b':'e'] = np.array(df.index.map(map_dict)).reshape(3,1)
df

    a   b   c   d   e
0   0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   0.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
2   0.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0


This isn't the desired result. I think they want the same result as MWE 1, with the same values in each column of a row.

@Barmar is correct. More than anything, I would like to understand why the approach of MWE 1 works and if it is a reasonable way of solving the problem.

Apologies, this technically does give the desired result. I was confused at first by the discrepancy between ints in dictionary values and floats in the dataframe. However, as mentioned, I am trying to understand what is happening MWE 1 rather than looking for another approach explicitly.
